# Python Program Breaks After 1 Run

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Thanks so much for Helping, It's fixed now thanks to you guys.

The problem was after I got my cps count the program delayed and froze. It stopped showing the cps.

I can't find out why this happens or how to fix it. The program is a cps counter, it works after 1 try then it breaks and freezes if I use it a second time.

I also have no idea where the code breaks, thank you so much.

Here is the code:

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
import time

clicks = 0
cps = 0
start = True

wn = Tk()
wn.title("Cps Counter")
wn.geometry("400x300")

def cps5():
    global start
    global cps
    global clicks
    global t1
    start = False
    time.sleep(5)
    cps = (clicks / 5)
    clicks = 0 
    CpsButton.config(text=clicks)
    CpsAmount.config(text=cps)
    start = True
    time.sleep(.1

t1 = threading.Thread(target=cps5)
t1.start()

def AddClicks():
    global clicks
    global start
    clicks += 1
    CpsButton.config(text=clicks)
    if start == True:
        cps5()

CpsButton = Button(wn, text=clicks, command=AddClicks, pady=15, padx=15)
CpsAmount = Label(wn, text=cps, pady=15, padx=15)

CpsAmount.pack()
CpsButton.pack()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're doing, and what it means when you say it "breaks". [MCVE]s aren't just about the code, they're about how you're using it, what you expect to happen in that case, and what *actually* happens (if there is a traceback, provide it).

Comment: Also, this code is broken as written (you'll get a `SyntaxError` around the `t1 =` line due to an unclosed paren above it). And it's incredibly unsafe to do cross-thread `tkinter` calls like you're doing; use the event loop to schedule it with `.after`, don't launch a thread to call `cps5`. And don't use `time.sleep`; the entire GUI will freeze while it's sleeping (again, that's what `.after` is for); at a guess, you think it's broken because of the `time.sleep`, not realizing that the GUI is just going to be non-responsive for a titch over five seconds while `cps5` is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
import time

clicks = 0
cps = 0
start = True

wn = Tk()
wn.title("Cps Counter")
wn.geometry("400x300")
clicks = 0
def cps5():
    global start
    global cps
    global clicks
    global t1
    start = False

    CpsButton.config(text=clicks)
    start = True




def AddClicks():
    global clicks
    global start
    clicks += 1
    CpsButton.config(text=clicks)
    if start == True:
        cps5()

CpsButton = Button(wn, text=clicks, command=AddClicks, pady=15, padx=15)
CpsAmount = Label(wn, text=cps, pady=15, padx=15)

CpsAmount.pack()
CpsButton.pack()


def Timer():
    global CpsAmount, cps, clicks
    for i in range(0, 5):
        time.sleep(1)
    cps = (clicks / 5)
    CpsAmount.config(text=cps)
    clicks = 0
    Timer()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=cps5)
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=Timer)
t2.start()
wn.mainloop()
```

I created a second thread for the counter, because time.sleep freezes the program and caused trouble.